# Can I increase linux entropy by using rng-daemon without hardware generator?

Tags: linux, random, linux-kernel, cryptography

I want to continuously increase `/prco/sys/random/entropy_avail` when it reduced.

I first check the `rngd` (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rng-tools)

It says `/dev/random` is very slow since it only collects entropy from device drivers and other (slow) sources and I think that is why we use `rngd`.

And it says `rngd` mainly uses hardware random number generators (TRNG), present in modern hardware like recent AMD/Intel processors, VIA Nano or even Raspberry Pi.

However, when I start `rngd` it says

```
[root@localhost init.d]# rngd 
can't open entropy source(tpm or intel/amd rng)
Maybe RNG device modules are not loaded
```

But I don't have Intel `RDRAND` confirmed by `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep rdrand`:

```
[root@localhost init.d]# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep rdrand | wc -l
0
```

If there is any possible resources that I can use?

Alternatively, is it possible making script to increase `/proc/sys/random/entropy_avail`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo apt-get install haveged